# Consequences of leaving Default Gateway blank in TCP/IPv4 Configuration?

Tags: ipv4, internet

Amateur here.

If I leave the default gateway blank in TCP/IPv4 configuration the client won't be able to reach other networks right?

But can other clients still reach the client with no gateway?

I'm trying to make the client unable to access the internet and vice versa.
Is leaving the gateway blank a good way to do that?
Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without the gateway, the PC can't get to another network, and devices on another network may be able to send something to that PC, but that PC can't reply, and it can't establish something like a TCP session. This is a very bad idea.

A better solution would be to put an ACL in you router or firewall for that PC's IP address.

Comment: Ok thank for the fast answer.
If I want the whole network to be unable to connect to the internet can I enter a range in my router?

Probably depends on the router

Comment: Right. ACLs use ranges, from `/32` for a single device all the way to `/0` for every device.